# error during the installation of the "maestro" package

Tags: mobile-application, maestro

> PS C:\Users\tgt587\Desktop\MMT> npm install -g maestro
> npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is
> considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API
> instead. npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path
> C:\Users\tgt587\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\maestro npm ERR!
> command failed npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c
> ./bin/welcome-message.sh npm ERR! '.' is not recognized as an internal
> or external command, npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> C:\Users\tgt587\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-12-11T07_31_42_603Z-debug-0.log
> PS C:\Users\tgt587\Desktop\MMT>

While installing maestro facing this error?

Need to install Maestro mobile automation tool using npm

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Please don't just dump stacktraces

Answer (score 0):

Maestro is not an npm package, and so cannot be installed using npm.

Installation for Mac/Linux is simply `curl -Ls "https://get.maestro.mobile.dev" | bash`.

It looks like you're on Windows, which is a little more complicated, in that you'll need to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux and Java first. There's a guide for that in the Maestro docs [here](https://maestro.mobile.dev/getting-started/installing-maestro/windows).